# Нельзя объявить метод статичным, почему?

Tags: java

когда метод ExcelDataConfig объявляю статичным то пишет ошибку: java: modifier static not allowed here. В чём может быть причина ? Спасибо !

```
public class ExcelDataConfig {
static XSSFWorkbook wb;
static XSSFSheet sheet;
static String excelPath = "C:\\UsersData.xlsx";

public static ExcelDataConfig() {
    try {
        File src = new File(excelPath);
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(src);
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static String getData(int row, int column) {
    sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    String data = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(column).getStringCellValue();
    return data;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что название метода совпадает с названием класса `ExcelDataConfig`, что свойственно конструктору класса, а конструктор не может быть `static`.